# Installing OpenVPN failing on AlmaLinux 8.4

Tags: openvpn, virtual-machines

I tried to install OpenVPN on my new AlmaLinux 8.4, but it's failing. There is no error log in syslog or in OpenVPN log.
This is the error I'm getting at the final stage of install process.

```
cp: cannot stat '/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service': No such file or directory
sed: can't read /etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service: No such file or directory
Failed to enable unit: Unit file openvpn@server.service does not exist.
Failed to restart openvpn@server.service: Unit openvpn@server.service not found.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/iptables-openvpn.service → /etc/systemd/system/iptables-openvpn.service.
```

I downloaded the script from `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Angristan/openvpn-install/master/openvpn-install.sh` and system processor is `AMD EPYC 7282`

I'm very new to AlmaLinux and I don't know whether OpenVPN will work or not on this server.
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this script is not supported for Almalinux and based on comments from the community it will add soon:
https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install/issues/871

another solution is changing your installation script based on the commit requested for commit ( it not confirmed )

https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install/commit/44e4c14a8725827a1f38e1c1a577438d2bff0fc9

Comment: Awsome clue.  I installed with that script and it's working. :)